# Return ViewModel Data to Javascript function MVC 4?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to pass the data of the view model to one js method and from there I need to pass the VM to another controller method to show the data.

here is what I have did:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var content = GetHomeContent('/Home/CastContent');
    if (content) {
        saveBDContent('/Message/Details/', content);
    }

});

function GetHomeContent(url) {
    var modelData;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                modelData = data;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            status = false;
        }
    })

   return modelData;
};

function saveBDContent(url, data) {
    var status = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "200") {
                status = true;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            status = false;
        }
    })

    return status;
};
```

The problem am facing is , the content I retrived from the method show the namespace of the ViewModel. When I pass that to the new controlled the Viewmodel content is coming null.

Do I need to add anything to get/Pass the proper content ?

The Dummy method skeleton

```
    public ActionResult CastContent()
    {
        CastVM broadcastVM = new CastVM();


        return Json( broadcastVM);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have missed out the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in my  controller method, I have added and the results are coming perfectly.

```
public ActionResult CastContent()
    {
        CastVM broadcastVM = new CastVM();


        return Json( broadcastVM,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and also I have set the HTTP status as post in the jquery method

Answer (score 1):

Do something like that in the Controller:

```
public JsonResult QuickSave(BookEntry bookEntry) {
    YourViewModel model = new YourViewModel();
    return Json(model);
}
```

EDIT >> The associated Javascript code is :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'The URL',
    data: 'The JSON data',
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (theViewModel) {
        // Do some JS stuff with your model
    },

    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Do some error stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see my edit. That's some working code, so I know it works.

Comment: Thanks Laurent PerrucheJ. As you have posted I have changed the Ajax method type to POST it is working apart from that we need to add the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet .I have updated the answer.